# Python - Converting an n-ary tree to a binary tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree, binary-tree

```
class Tree:

        def __init__(self, new_key):
    self.__key = new_key    # Root key value
    self.__children = []     # List of children
    self.__num_of_descendants = 0 # Number of Descendants of this node    

# Prints the given tree
def printTree(self):
    return self.printTreeGivenPrefix("", True)   

# Prints the given tree with the given prefix for the line
# last_child indicates whether the node is the last of its parent"s child
# or not
def printTreeGivenPrefix(self, line_prefix, last_child):
    print(line_prefix, end="")
    if last_child:
        print("â””--> ", end="")
    else:
        print("|--> ", end="")
    print(self.__key)

    if len(self.__children) > 0:
        next_pre = line_prefix
        if last_child:
            next_pre += "     "
        else:
            next_pre += "|    "
        for child_index in range(len(self.__children)-1):
            self.__children[child_index].\
                printTreeGivenPrefix(next_pre, False)
        self.__children[-1].printTreeGivenPrefix(next_pre, True)

def __repr__(self):
    return "[" + str(self.__key) + "".join(
        [ repr(child) for child in self.__children ]) + "]"

# This static function will load a tree with the format of below:
# [root[child_1][child_2]...[child_n]]
# Each child_i can be a tree with the above format, too
# pos is the position in the given string
@staticmethod
def loadTree(tree_str, pos = 0):
    new_node = None
    while pos < len(tree_str):
        if tree_str[pos] == "[":
            pos += 1
            new_node = Tree(tree_str[pos])
            while pos < len(tree_str) and tree_str[pos + 1] != "]":
                pos += 1
                child_tree, pos = Tree.loadTree(tree_str, pos)
                if child_tree:
                    new_node.__children.append(child_tree)
                    new_node.__num_of_descendants += \
                        1 + child_tree.__num_of_descendants
            return new_node, pos + 1
        else:
            pos += 1
    return new_node, pos

def find_largest(self):
    if self.__num_of_descendants == 1:
        return self.__children[0]

    else:
        largest_child = self.__children[0]
        for child in self.__children:
            if child.__num_of_descendants > \
               largest_child.__num_of_descendants:
                largest_child = child
            if child.__num_of_descendants == \
               largest_child.__num_of_descendants:
                if child.__key > largest_child.__key:
                    largest_child = child
    return largest_child

def convert_to_binary_tree(self):
    if self.__num_of_descendants != 0:
        if self.__num_of_descendants < 3:
            for child in self.__children:
                child.convert_to_binary_tree()

        if self.__num_of_descendants > 2:
            left_child = self.__children[0]
            for child in self.__children[1:]:
                if len(child.__children) > len(left_child.__children):
                    left_child = child
                elif len(child.__children) == len(left_child.__children):
                    if child.__key > left_child.__key:
                        left_child = child
            self.__children.remove(left_child)
            self.__num_of_descendants -= 1

            right_child = self.__children[0]
            for child in self.__children[1:]:
                if len(child.__children) > len(right_child.__children):
                    right_child = child
                elif len(child.__children) == len(right_child.__children):
                    if child.__key > right_child.__key:
                        right_child = child
            self.__children.remove(right_child)
            self.__num_of_descendants -= 1
            print(self.__num_of_descendants)
            print(self.__children)
            print(left_child)
            print(right_child)

            #Move remaining children two either left_child or right_child.
            while self.__num_of_descendants != 0:
                largest_child = self.find_largest()
                print(largest_child)
                if left_child.__num_of_descendants < \
                   right_child.__num_of_descendants:
                    left_child.__children.append(largest_child)
                    left_child.__num_of_descendants += 1
                    self.__children.remove(largest_child)
                    self.__num_of_descendants -= 1                        

                elif left_child.__num_of_descendants > \
                   right_child.__num_of_descendants:
                    right_child.__children.append(largest_child)
                    right_child.__num_of_descendants += 1
                    self.__children.remove(largest_child)
                    self.__num_of_descendants -= 1                        

                elif left_child.__num_of_descendants == \
                   right_child.__num_of_descendants:
                    if left_child.__key > right_child.__key:
                        left_child.__children.append(largest_child)
                        left_child.__num_of_descendants += 1
                        self.__children.remove(largest_child)
                        self.__num_of_descendants -= 1                            
                    else:
                        right_child.__children.append(largest_child)
                        right_child.__num_of_descendants += 1
                        self.__children.remove(largest_child)
                        self.__num_of_descendants -= 1
            #Now run recursion on left and right binary children.
            self.__children.append(left_child)
            self.__children.append(right_child)
            self.__num_of_descendants = 2
            print(self.__children)
            for child in self.__children:
                child.convert_to_binary_tree()
def main():
    tree, processed_chars = Tree.loadTree('[z[y][x][w][v]]]')
    tree.convert_to_binary_tree()
    tree.printTree()
    print(tree)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have to convert a given tree into a binary tree. If a node in the tree has more than 2 children, I have to assign the child with the most descendants as the left node and the child with the second largest number of descendents as the right child. The remaining children are added as following:
1) Take child with largest number of descendants
2) Add it to Left/Right node. Whichever has fewer children at that time.

*If at any time I need to select the child with the largest number of descendants, but there are two+ with the same number of descendents, I take the one with the larger key value.

```
I get a print out like this...
2 #Number of 'z' children after left and right node chosen.
[[w], [v]] #Children of 'z'
[y] #Binary left child of 'z'
[x] #Binary right child of 'z'
[w] #This is a bug. It should be choosing 'v' as larger child of 'z' and assigning it to left child 'y'
[v] #This is a bug. see above.
[[y[w]], [x[v]]] #These are the children of node 'z'
â””--> z #schematic of binary tree
     |--> y
     |    â””--> w
     â””--> x
          â””--> v
[z[y[w]][x[v]]] #final binary tree
```

Comment: Aside: there's no reason to prefix your variables with `__` here.  If you insist, you can use `_` as a friendly reminder that some aren't meant to be modified outside of the class, but even that's often overkill.

Comment: Yeah, I don't like the way they're named either, but my instructor insists...

Comment: Can you check the indentation of the code? Are the `main` function and `if __name__ == "__main__"` boilerplate really indented under the `class`, or are they actually at the top level?

Comment: Well, if the there are more than three children, than that nodes children have to be rearranged. That is, if a node has three children the largest two values are assigned as the left and right child of the node, while the remaining children are assigned to the new left or right child. If the node only has two children than it's already in the binary tree format and nothing needs to be done. But, I want to run the formatting on those 2 children in case one of those have 3+ children.

Comment: Sorry, indentation is off. main function and if __name__ == "__main__" are at main level.

Comment: Sticking `print` at a few places suggests that it's getting caught in the `for child in self.__children` loop, in a state where `left_child is right_child` and `left_child is self`, and so `self.__children` grows and grows.  Usually that's a sign that the recursion isn't shutting off early enough, but it's past midnight EST. :^)

Answer (score 0):

DSM's comment helped me see what is going on. After you pick `left_child` and `right_child` in the first parts of your `convert_to_binary_tree` method, you're not removing them from the list of children. This means that later, when you go to add all of the current node's children into new parents, you're adding the left and right children to themselves (or each other). When you recurse into those children, you can end up infinitely looping.

I don't really understand the logic of your `left_child` and `right_child` selections, so I don't have fixed code to suggest to you. A quick but ugly fix would be to put a `if child in (left_child, right_child): continue` statement at the top of the for loop where you're assigning the other children to new parents.

Note that there's another bug in your current code, where the descendent counts for the left and right children will become incorrect. That's because you're not updating the count when you push some of their former siblings into them as children.

Comment: Hey thanks for taking the time to look at the code. I ended up scraping most of it, after realizing what you just posted. I updated my code, but, for some reason I still get a bug. See updated post if you have the time :)

Comment: I've narrowed it down. For whatever reason the program enters the def find_largest(self):
                if child.__key > largest_child.__key:
                    largest_child = child
It isn't registering v > w.